# Save user with generated password with Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save a user with an generated password and username, and I am having a little trouble.

My view.py looks like this:

```
...
if request.method == "POST":

    u = get_username(request.POST.get('first_name', '').lower() + "." + request.POST.get('last_name', '').lower())
    p = User.objects.make_random_password(length = 6)

    form = PrincipalRegistrationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():

        ...

        new_user = form.save(uname = u, pword = p)

        return HttpResponseRedirect("/path/to/site")
...
```

and my forms.py like this:

```
class PrincipalRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm ):

    first_name = forms.CharField(label = 'First name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(label = 'Last name')

    school = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = School.objects.all())
    profile_pic = forms.FileField(required=False)



    def save(self,commit = True, uname = "unkown", pword = "unknown"):   

        user = super(PrincipalRegistrationForm, self).save(commit = False)

        user.username = uname
        user.set_password = make_password(pword)

        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']


        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
            super(PrincipalRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
            self.fields.pop('username')
            self.fields.pop('password1')
            self.fields.pop('password2')
```

The username is generated by a helper function and is made of the fname and lname and it is send to the save function like in the code, it works fine (if I type the password by hand). Now I want the password to generate and save like the username but I having problems with that. I am getting these errors:

```
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: u'password1'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py in save, line 121
```

Thanks for any help and I appreciate any advice on how I should write the code or if should change something.

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/siteadmin/add/principal

Django Version: 1.7.5
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'app_accounts',
 'app_schools',
 'app_school_subjects')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "/path/to/ednevnik/app_accounts/views.py" in add_principal
      80.             new_user = form.save(uname = u, pword = p)
    File "/path/to/ednevnik/app_accounts/forms.py" in save
      64.         user = super(PrincipalRegistrationForm, self).save(commit = False)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in save
      121.         user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])

    Exception Type: KeyError at /siteadmin/add/principal
    Exception Value: u'password1'
```

**Solved:**

```
def save(self, commit = True, uname = "unkown", pword = "unknown"):   
    # Adding this line solved my problem
    self.cleaned_data['password1'] = pword

    user = super(PrincipalRegistrationForm, self).save(commit = False)

    user.username = uname
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']

    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

Comment: I see a couple of things: `user.set_password` is a function, and needs to be called like this: `user.set_password(password)`. Then, it's not an error, but you don't need to rewrite all the code for the `save` function. You should be inheriting from the parent class, and execute your code before it.

Comment: Just verify what you have in `self.cleaned_data`, you don't have this `password1`

Comment: That's it! After I added 'self.cleaned_data["password1"] = pword' before the 'user = super(PrincipalRegistrationForm, self).save(commit = False)' line in the save function, everything works fine :D Thnaks!

Comment: You should really think about the code you wrote, and try to improve it. As I said in my post, you can get rid of a lot of useless code. Glad I could be useful

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but my current goal is that all works as I want. Thanks for the advice and I'll definitely take it into account!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `class Meta: exclude = ['somefield']` and my way to solve the problem by changing the instance of the form before doing the normal save.

Comment: there is no field called "password1", there is only "password" so if you exclude only "password" you will be fine